# Placeholder en Javascript - DOM

Tags: javascript

Si queremos informar de la información que debe tener un campo *input* en *HTML* ,por ejemplo, se debe utilizar el atributo `"placeholder"`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="First name"><br>
  <input type="text" name="lname" if="lname" placeholder="Last name"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

¿Cómo se podría utilizar `"placeholder"` para código *Javascript*? Cogiendo el valor del `id`, `document.getElementById("fname")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.getElementsByName('fname')[0].placeholder='Tu nuevo placeholder';
document.getElementById('lname').placeholder='Tu placeholder 2';
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br>
  <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Y tambien puedes por el Id

```
document.getElementById('fname').placeholder='Tu placeholder';
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Para recoger el valor del "id" sobra la letra "s" del "getElementsById".

Comment: @omaza1990 Si, y tambien el index [0] del arreglo, ahi lo actualice :D